# send email symfony swiftmailer

Tags: php, symfony, swiftmailer

I'm trying to send an email via swiftmailer and gmail.

I have put in my config.yml:

```
swiftmailer:
    transport: gmail
    username:  xxx@gmail.com
    password:  xxx
```

If I use it im localhost, putting them im config_dev.yml, it work fine, if I use it im localhost but with the prod version it work fine, but if I use my prod version in the server it doesn't work.

Somebody knows why?

Thnaks
Best regards

Answer (score 0):

Are the right parameters set in parameters.yml? like so:

```
# app/config/parameters.yml
parameters:
    # ...
    mailer_transport: gmail
    mailer_host:      ~
    mailer_user:      your_gmail_username
    mailer_password:  your_gmail_password
```

Also, you could try to intercept emails (i think ths can only be done in development) and see whats happening when you try to send mail:

```
# app/config/config_dev.yml
web_profiler:
    intercept_redirects: true
```

You could also try signing up to a free mandrill account (https://mandrill.com/) and using your mandrill smtp settings in parameters.yml and check if that works instead.

Comment: It's the same with mandrill, im localhost it work, but not im server!

Comment: When you say it's working in localhost, are you using /app_dev.php in your url?

Comment: it work with app_dev and with app in localhost, but wit app.php in server don't work

Comment: Then its probably your server? what server are you using? check the smtp port being used and make sure it's not blocked.

Comment: Yes, it's possible, but I don't know how to check that. I have done that more simple. Just use the mail transport system.

Answer (score 0):

Is possible that You have a hosting, if You want send emails in hosting You can do it with php function mail():

```
$to      = 'email@domain.com';
$subject   = 'subject';
$msg       = 'Hi';
$others     = 'From: contact@domain.com' ."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $msg, $others);
```